# the type of out is erroneous

Tags: java, io, system.out

I'm working on a java project in Netbeans 8.2. And suddenly, I started receiving errors whenever I type :

```
System.out.println();
System.err.println();
```

Error shows : **The type of out is erroneous** ( same goes for err)

Also, when I tried

```
import java.io.PrintStream
```

an Error shows that PrintStream doesnt exist in package *IO*.

What should I do to resolve this problem ? and is there any replacements for ***System.out.println()***

Comment: Is this an error that occurs when you *run* the program, or something that Netbeans is throwing at you? If it is the latter, I'd recommend reinstalling Netbeans.

Comment: It is an error that Netbeans throw at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same error occurred to me as well, but it was when I would copy-paste some code and some lines would throw such error, I found out that deleting cache can fix error. First close netbeans, and go to cache folder.

Cache folder is located in C:\Users\"YOUR USERNAME"\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\

But you can also copy address from netbeans, go to help -> about and you will see **Cache directory**

Inside Cache folder you will find another folder which name is version of netbeans, in your case it should be 8.2, just rename this folder to something different because you want to keep it for case something bad happens, then run netbeans and it should create new folder called 8.2, if everything is working properly you can now remove renamed folder and continue with your work.